# Does Pi Zero Have built-in-audio component?

Tags: raspbian, hardware, audio, pi-zero, cpu

I am looking to buy a Raspberry Pi Zero for my retro gaming project. I am asking wherher the Raspberry Pi Zero has any built-in internal audio speaker in the chip itself or not?

If there isn't, is there any way to make the chip give out a BEEP-sound without any additional components. Like for example raising the clock rate of the CPU until it gives out audible noises?

Comment: No, and no.  You need external components.

Answer (score 3):

There's no particularly good way to make the board as-delivered make sound.  Audio by default goes out over HDMI (which is the best option IMO).

You can pop a relatively simple lowpass filter and amp on the alternate function of two GPIO pins for PWM (cheap and not horrible audio).  I did a project like that for a little gag gift I have a co-worker last year. See [adafruit's site for details.](https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-the-raspberry-pi-zero/audio-outputs)

Alternatively, you could hook up an [I2S codec](http://www.runeaudio.com/forum/i2s-connection-to-an-external-dac-t1337.html) or just use a [low-end USB speaker with built-in codec.](http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/2014-01-31-logitech-s150-usb-stereo-speakers). You might even be able to jam the zero into the speaker chassis itself if the dimensions are right :-)

Answer (score 1):

For simple beeps, I use the [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) library.  This library enables hardware-timed PWM on all GPIO.  The only drawback (a minor one imo) is that it requires you to load a daemon before calling the library.  Just connect a piezo beeper between the slected GPIO pin and ground.

```
import pigpio
from time import sleep

pig = pigpio.pi()
BEEPER = 25 # GPIO pin for the beeper (can be any GPIO 0 - 31)

def beep(freq,ms): # generate a beep at the specified frequency and length (in milliseconds)
    pig.set_PWM_dutycycle(BEEPER,50)
    pig.set_PWM_frequency(BEEPER,freq)
    sleep(ms/1000.0)
    pig.set_PWM_frequency(BEEPER,0)
    pig.set_PWM_dutycycle(BEEPER,0)

beep(1004,250) # quarter second of 1004Hz tone
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically no, you either need a buzzer for simple BEEP stuff hooked to one of the GPIO or using HDMI adaptor that contain an audio jack. for more complex, a bit permanent solution you can build one of pwm based audio like what Bj Black already mention